# Navigating around python code

Tags: python, branch, action

I'm new to python and I am making myself a simple game to help myself learn it. I've got to a point where in the game I want there to be a decision that affects all the actions after it.

```
print ("Left down the hallway? Or right?")

action4 = input()       
if action4 == ("left"):
    print ("You turn left and proceed down this hallway")
elif action4 == ("right"):
    print ("You turn right and proceed down this hallway")

#The game will branch off from this
```

Can I set out two different versions of code branching from this. One where you choose to go right and one where you choose to go left. I want each direction to give a different game entirely. How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just call a different function based upon the if condition that calls the seperate game versions?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, sorry. Could you elaborate? I'm only a novice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using two functions to do the job. It would look something like this:

```
# define your functions first

def function_left():
    # do something here

def function_right():
    # do something here

#then call your functions from the if/elif block

action4 = input("Left down the hallway? Or right?")       
if action4 == ("left"):
    print ("You turn left and proceed down this hallway")
    function_left()
elif action4 == ("right"):
    print ("You turn right and proceed down this hallway")
    function_right()
```

Comment: Would these functions need to include all of the code for each version of the game?

Comment: Not really, you could define other functions as well. Basically if you have a task that you will perform more than once you should define a function for performing that task. Does that make sense?